# Can avrdude address individual usbtiny programmers?

Tags: avr, multiplexer, avrdude, isp

I'm envisioning a panel programming jig. In my mind, it consists of a Raspberry Pi, a powered USB hub, and a collection of usbtiny clones each connected to a pogo jig and a target on a panel.

The only question I haven't yet worked out is, when invoking avrdude, I can use -c to tell it to use usbtiny... but how can I tell it *which* usbtiny I want it to use? The plan is to use a script to go through them all one at a time, and IMHO just attaching a bunch of programmers is easier than trying to come up with a bolt-on to multiplex the SPI bus from one programmer to all the targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple USBasp or USBtinyISP devices can be identified by their connection information. From the AVRDUDE manual, appendix B, ["Troubleshooting"](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_20.html#Troubleshooting):

> - Problem: Multiple USBasp or USBtinyISP programmers connected simultaneously are not found.
>
>   Solution: The USBtinyISP code supports distinguishing multiple programmers based on their bus:device connection tuple that describes their place in the USB hierarchy on a specific host. This tuple can be added to the *-P usb* option, similar to adding a serial number on other USB-based programmers.
>
>   The actual naming convention for the bus and device names is operating-system dependant; AVRDUDE will print out what it found on the bus when running it with (at least) one *-v* option. By specifying a string that cannot match any existing device (for example, *-P usb:xxx*), the scan will list all possible candidate devices found on the bus.
>
>   Examples:
>
>   ```
>   avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega8 -P usb:003:025 (Linux)
>   avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega8 -P usb:/dev/usb:/dev/ugen1.3 (FreeBSD 8+)
>   avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega8 \
>     -P usb:bus-0:\\.\libusb0-0001--0x1781-0x0c9f (Windows)
>   ```

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad there's a solution. I found lots of doc for avrdude, but not that chunk of the manual. Thanks!